# Java Email App Builds, Can't Run, Missing ClassDef

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, javax

```
javac SendEmail.java -cp ".;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javax.mail.jar"
```

Successfully makes SendEmail.class

```
java SendEmail -cp ".;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javax.mail.jar"
```

Results in:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I have tried putting the javax.mail.jar in both the jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib and the jre1.8.0_111\lib directories. I have tried putting it in the same directory as the SendEmail.java file. I've read the documentation and watched the tutorials. Why is this still happening? I'm using version 1.5.6 of the jar.

Comment: Try adding a ``\`` after `C:`. Also, if you list the content of `javax.mail.jar` with a zip utility (e.g. WinZip), does it have an entry named `javax/mail/Address.class`?

Comment: Same result, and yes, Address.class and all the rest are there.

Comment: Might want to move the `javax.mail.jar` outside of your JRE install per the `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`

Comment: I did try that immediately after, but it's the same error.